# Getting a for loop to ignore missing values - R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, merge

I've got this for loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(class.data$ID)) {
  class.data$FinalExam_GroupMCScore[i]=mc.data$PSYC.260.Exam....2017.3.
  [which(mc.data$SIS.User.ID == class.data$FinalExam_MCGroupNumber[i])]
}
```

To merge two class grade files. Students did a part of their final exam in groups. The problem I'm having is that not everyone opted to do the group portion so they are missing a code for class.data$FinalExam_MCGroupNumber. The for loop gets hung up on these missing values and I can't get past. I suspect I need a an if statement embedded in there but I'm not familiar enough with R yet to write one in.

I've looked at some of the other posts on this and they don't help just because I'm having a tough time seeing how to embed an if or ifelse with a more complicated function following. Any help would be appreciated! I just want it to assign an NA on FinalExam_GroupMCScore to all students with NA on FinalExam_MCGroupNumber and carry on as normal!

Thank you!!

Comment: To merge two files, try using the `merge` function instead of a custom for loop.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, please create a *small* reproducible example [as described here], with sample input and desired output. 5-10 rows of data should be plenty.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply! I don't think merge will work because I'm simply trying to bring the data from one column in the second data file into another column in the first data file.

Comment: That's pretty much what `merge` does. And `merge` will create your `NA`s by default. But I can't be sure it will work for you without seeing sample data...